# WPF - Vertical scroll bar of list view does not let scroll through individual items

Tags: wpf, listview, scrollbar, stackpanel

I have a listview inside a stackpanel. There is a vertical scroll bar in it. It is visible too. The issue is that when it is scrolled , it does not scroll through the individual items of the listview. Scrolling through set of items by set of items is possible.

```
       <stackpanel>

             <ListView  ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                       ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True">

                   <GridView>

                       ..................
                   </GridView>

             </ListView>

       </stackpanel>
```

I found some answer somewhere and it said this happens since the listview is there inside a stackpanel. Is there a solution to this ? If it can be done, without removing the stackpanel then that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

I set the property **ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll** to **False** and it worked.

```
       ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False"
```